# Query one single value with one of a collection in NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

Inside an ElasticSearch instance, I was trying to search elements by matching one field with multiple values. ie:

```
public class User
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set;}
}
```

If I have multiple users and I want to filter by the ones who's name is John or Mike, until version 6.x, this implementation was working:

```
    private QueryContainer ApplyNameFilter(QueryContainerDescriptor<User> q, SearchParameters searchParameters)
    {
        return (searchParameters.Names != null && searchParameters.Names .Any()) ?
             q.Terms(z => z.Field(f => f.Name).Terms(searchParameters.Names))
             :
             q;
    }
```

Notice that inside SearchParameters, Names is a IEnumerable

Once I updated ElasticSearch instance to 7.x, also NEST library to 7.3.1, this filter is not working anymore.

Having a look to the [Search NEST documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html) I am not fully sure of what I have to refactor there in order to make it work again.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "this filter is not working anymore.", what is not working - does it throw an exception? Does it not generate the correct query? Does it not return the expected results?

Comment: With this approach, the client is not retrieving any result, when in fact if there is data that match the filter to be displayed.

Comment: Trying the solution suggested by @jaspreet-chahal above worked for me, thank you both for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-query-usage.html) field is used to match not_analyzed text(text not broken up in tokens).
Check the mapping of field "Name" it will be having a subfield keyword with type:"keyword" or you will need to create one in mapping

you can try below query
 q.Terms(z => z.Field(f => f.Name.Suffix("keyword")).Terms(searchParameters.Names))

Comment: It worked for me, I will investigate more about not_analyzed text. Thank you a lot for your help :)

Comment: Glad could be of help